# simplemodal dialog scrolls page to top in Mobile Safari on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, scroll, mobile-safari, simplemodal

I am using simplemodal on a page for inline editing of records in a table. Everything works perfectly in desktop browsers, but on the iPad (where it will be used heavily), bringing up the dialog causes the page to jump to the top before showing the dialog. Jumping to the top of the screen each time on a long page is cumbersome and I would like it to stay in place. Is there anyway to get it to appear without causing the scroll? I love simplemodal and would like to use it on the iPad.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an iPad to test with. It almost sounds like the links are href='#' and they are not being prevented from firing. Can you confirm?

Comment: I replace the a href # links with just an onlick on an image with no link,it makes no difference. If used with a link, I was returning false but it had no effect. In doing some research I saw mention of Facebox not causing the scrolling problem, I'm going to try it to see if that resolves it. I would love to keep using simplemodal, I really like it.

Comment: Facebox worked. It does not cause the scrolling, but I still prefer simplemodal. I am not sure what is different between the two scripts in relation to the popup.

Comment: I noticed jQuery UI's dialog also does not cause the jump.